# bash terminal [\t] (time) is not same timezone as 'date'

Tags: bash, time, timezone

In my .bashrc file I configured how I would like my prompt to be displayed. My .bashrc is sourced in .bash_profile. The command in the .bashrc file is:

```
PS1='[\t] \u@\h is $PWD :: '
```

I switched the user (for me) timezone to GMT+0 using tzselect. The problem I am having is that using the date command I am getting the GMT time (which I am pleased with) but the terminal prompt is still on the system time (even after logging in and logging out), which I am not pleased with.

How can I get the terminal to display the time in the time format that I, the user, am specifying?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't say how you set the timezone, but since you set it for your own user, that has to be by setting the `TZ` variable. Bash (at least version 4.1.5) has some quirks when it comes to taking a `TZ` change into account: the change is only reflected after the shell has started an external command (it has to be an external command, forking a subshell isn't enough, nor is executing built-ins).

```
bash-4.1$ PS1='\t '
12:31:05 export TZ=Asia/Tokyo
12:31:12
12:31:13 echo foo
foo
12:31:14 /bin/echo foo
foo
19:31:17
```

So if you set `TZ` in your `.bash_profile` and you don't happen to start an external command, you will still see the time in the old timezone at the first prompt.

```
export TZ=GMT
# Refresh bash's idea of $TZ for prompt display purposes.
# As of bash 4.1, this requires running an external command!
if [[ $- = *i* ]]; then command true; fi
```

Comment: bash-4.2 reacts immediately to a change in `TZ`. Apparently that's been the case since 2.0 (http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/CHANGES).

Comment: @Mat My tests showed otherwise. Upon further investigation (in bash 4.1), bash only takes a `TZ` change into account after it has executed an external command (!). So it works, but not immediately.

Comment: Ok, needs bash >= 4.2.6 - patch 4.2.5 makes it work, 4.2.6 fixes a segfault in that patch :-)

Comment: thanks for the solution. Interesting enough. The machine this is occurring on is running bash3.00.15(1)-release. I am not able to get it to work with this version even with the suggestions. Though I am able to get it to work at home where I am running 4.2.8(1). Again, thank you.

Comment: @DanCat Did you try `exec`ing another copy, as I suggested in [my original answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/39701/1)? I edited that out because it's complex and my assertion that it was the only way turned out to be wrong in bash 4.1. Maybe you need to do that in older versions; if so I'll edit it back in.

Comment: @Gilles I am getting an error when I use the suggestions in your original answer. error is on `if[[ -z $TZ]]; then` and is the line prior 'reload_if_interactive=` with nothing after equals? Another question I have for you. Will cron use this TZ info? I need a script to use the updated time as the system's time is not on the same TZ. I have the scripts run at the time specified on the computer's time but the `date` call in the script needs to on the updated TZ. Thanks.

Comment: @DanCat Did you really type what I wrote? Note that spaces are required around `[[` and before `]]`. If so, copy-paste the error message. `reload_if_interactive=` sets the variable to an empty value. Cron is a daemon, it has its own environment. Add a line with `TZ=GMT` in your crontab (this sets the environment for cron jobs, but does not influence the times at which the jobs run).